# Makefile cannot find rule for objects

Tags: makefile

My source is distributed across multiple directories which are not under the same root. I'm don't want to go into the reasons why this is the case and at the moment I just want to compile it. I've written a `Makefile` to compile my code but it is telling me that it can't find a rule to create object (`.o`) files. The code for `Makefile` is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
TARGET=main

ROOT_DIR:=.
BUILD_DIR:=$(ROOT_DIR)/build
OBJ_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/obj
TARGET_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/bin

OBJ:= src/main.o \
    ../src/system.o \
    ../../LTC2947/src/LTC2947.o \
    ../../spi/src/my_spi.o

INC_DIR:=src ../src/ ../../LTC2947/src ../../spi/src/

CFLAGS := -O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -DDEBUG -L$(LIB_DIR)

#====================================================
TARGET_BIN:=$(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)
_INC_DIR:=$(foreach _dir,$(INC_DIR), -I$(_dir))

# absolute paths for object files
_OBJ:=$(foreach _path, $(OBJ), $(abspath $(_path))) 
# prepend $(OBJ_DIR) to the oejct full paths
_OBJ2:=$(patsubst %,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
# Remove double slashes
_OBJ:=$(shell echo $(_OBJ2) | sed 's,//,/,g')
OBJ_DIRS:=$(dir $(_OBJ))

BUILD_DIRS:= $(OBJ_DIRS) $(TARGET_DIR)

_CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) $(_INC_DIR)

all: create-build-dirs $(TARGET_BIN)

$(TARGET_BIN): $(_OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(_CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
    find . -type f \( -name *~ -o -name core \) -exec rm -f {} \;

create-build-dirs:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIRS)
```

**EDIT**

This is the error that is generated

No rule to make target /home/user/projects/myproject/spi/src/my_spi.o

Comment: Where do you want `my_spi.o` to go?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the exact error messages you're seeing (cut and paste), not an abstract description.

There are many issues here, but fundamentally this rule:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

tells make how to build a file *PATH*.o from a file *PATH*.c.  The values of *PATH* in both these files must be exactly identical strings.  In your environment (if you provided the error message it would be more clear) it appears that you're creating object files in `$(OBJ_DIR)` for source files that are not there, so there's no way that the these paths are identical.  This means that you are asking make to build a target `$(OBJ_DIR)/foo/bar.o`, and make will try to find a file `$(OBJ_DIR)/foo/bar.c` and if it can't this rule doesn't match.

A few other notes:

- you don't need to use `foreach` with `abspath`; it takes multiple names.  You can just say `$(abspath $(OBJ))`.
- you don't need a `sed` shell command to replace `//` with `/`; you can just use `$(subst //,/,$(_OBJ2))`
- you won't be able to use parallel builds here reliably because of the way you're creating output directories; they may be created in parallel with compile lines that want to use them.

Comment: I provided the error message in the edit. I think I understand what you saying about PATH.o from PATH.c. I can't figure out how create .o from .c when files are located in different directories. How would I got about it without having a Makefile that is too complicated?

Comment: That error message means something is not right about your makefile, since (as far as I can tell) you want your object files to appear in the `obj` directory, but the error message doesn't list that.  I don't understand why you're listing object files, not source files, in the `OBJ` variable, then trying to massage them to be prefixed with `OBJ_DIR`.  Maybe if you tried to write (clearly) in text what you want to achieve we could see why your makefile is not doing that.  Something like, "my source files are here, I want my object files to be there" with examples.

Comment: "A makefile that is too complicated" is a subjective thing.  Without understanding exactly where your source files are and where you want your object files to be put we can't say for sure.  However, the only way make can find a relationship between object and source files is through rules and you'll have to define them.  If you have lots of different source directories and you want to put the output in different directories which are not related to the source directories, then you have to write a different rule for each directory.